# Segue after firebase download/upload completes

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to run some code after firebase has finished its downloading/uploading (eg segue or refresh)

for eg

I have x3 save functions which all have code to update both storage and database of certain data (eg text and images)

```
save1()
save2()
save3()
```

when an IBAction is performed I would like these functions to run, and on completion if their is no error to perform another function on completion (segue or refresh)

these 3 save function currently work within the IBAction

```
@IBAction func saveTap(_ sender: Any) {

save1()
save2()
save3()

}
```

Save function as follows:

(I check if image has been changed, then upload process begins)

```
 func save1(){

    if image1.image == nil {
        let gender = userGender.text
        self.databaseRef.child("users").child(gender!).child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("images").child("imageOne").removeValue { (error, ref) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)}
        }
        let imageRef = self.storage.child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("image1")
        imageRef.delete { error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                print("Photo 1 image deleted")}
        }

    } else {

        //Firebase child references
        let profileImageRef = storage.child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("image1")
        let metaData = StorageMetadata()
        metaData.contentType = "image1/jpeg"
        //Firebase child references

        //change uiimageview to uiimage for upload
        guard let image = image1.image else
        {return}
        //change uiimageview to uiimage for upload

        //Send to firebase storage
        profileImageRef.putData(image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1)!, metadata: metaData) { (data, error) in
            if error == nil
            {print("Photo 1 uploaded to storage")}
            else
            {print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)}}
        //Send to firebase storage


        //Update firebase database
        profileImageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error!)
                return}

            if let profilePhotoUrl = url?.absoluteString{
                let newValuesForProfile = profilePhotoUrl
                let gender = self.userGender.text
                self.databaseRef.child("users").child(gender!).child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("images").child("imageOne").setValue(newValuesForProfile, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                    if error != nil{
                        print(error!)
                        return}
                    print("Photo 1 updated in database")})}})
        //Update firebase database
    }
```

I need the uploads to complete before the segues are performed as the next view will be refreshing to the saved data that i'm trying to upload.

any help would be great, been at this for weeks now :( iv tried completion handlers but no luck as of yet.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think `dispatchGroup` fits with your case

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

dispatchGroup.enter()
save1 { dispatchGroup.leave() }

dispatchGroup.enter()
save2 { dispatchGroup.leave() }



dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
  self.perFormSegue//////
}
```

//

// e.x structure

```
func save1(completion:@escaping()->()) {

  firesCallBack {       
   if success {
      completion()
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) unfortunately when I input this to my IBAction I get and error "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"

Comment: ok thanks. I have updated my question with the details of the save function. where should I put my completions. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the changes are saved with .childChanged somehow like this:

```
    save1()
    save2()
    save3()

let ref: DatabaseReference!
ref = /YourDirectDatabaseReferenceForTheChangedNode/
ref.observe(.childChanged, with: {(snaphost) -> Void in

    }
})
```

Maybe you should use UIActivityIndicatorView aswell to show something is going in the background.

```
@IBAction func saveTap(_ sender: Any) {

           save1()
           save2()
           save3()

        let activity: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
            activity.center = self.view.center
            activity.hidesWhenStopped = true
            activity.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .whiteLarge
            self.view.addSubview(activity)

         let ref: DatabaseReference!
         ref = /YourDirectDatabaseReferenceForTheChangedNode/
         ref.observe(.childChanged, with: {(snaphost) -> Void in

           activity.stopAnimating()
           if UIApplication.shared.isIgnoringInteractionEvents {
              UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
           }
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "backhome", sender: self)
        }
    })
 }
```

Replace /YourDirectDatabaseReferenceForTheChangedNode/ with the correct child (what should change after save).

Comment: hi, thanks for you reply:) how do I perform a segue with this ? my segue is         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "backhome", sender: self), I wish to implement this after the uploading is complete,  thanks again

Comment: Check my edit :) My question: all the three save() method is save to firebase with different childs?

Comment: yes so basically I have a user that has a node with 3 images. these 3 images get saved when the user hits save. once the save is complete id like to head back to their own page and update. I already have the updates in place on the next controller that work fine. the problem is the segue happens to fast and then the download happens before the upload is complete

Comment: Maybe you should make it in one method, it's easier.

Comment: im not that skilled im afraid :( iv only been coding for around 6 months self taught. its a very slow process lol.  I would no how to edit my function to upload all my images. thanks again for helping me out :) iv updated my question with the function for uploading I use.